# Discrete Mathematics Vs Numerical Analysis

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

How hard, broad and complex is the field of Discrete Mathematics in comparison to Numerical Analysis for independent learner?

Comment: Discrete math tends to be very broad but elementary, covering many different topics from combinatorics, number theory, graph theory, etc. Numerical analysis is much more focused in scope.

Comment: Any branch of mathematics will turn out to be very taxing. It's research is done by some very bright people doing their very best. To say some branch is easier/simpler than another is just not knowing them deeply enough.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, "Discrete Mathematics" encompasses a large part of mathematics, including combinatorics, graph theory, game theory, theoretical computer science, and much of number theory.  However, 
a textbook with "Discrete Mathematics" in the title will usually
confine itself to a rather elementary coverage of some of those topics. 
Related to this, university courses labelled "Discrete Mathematics" are
often targeted at students with a relatively weak mathematical background.
To get at the deeper material, you'll need something labelled with one of the individual topics: "Combinatorics", "Graph Theory", etc.